# Is there a way to change the scope of the state persistence of a custom rally app from the current user scope to the whole subscription scope?

Tags: rally

From reading the rally docs, state persistence in custom rally apps is scoped to the current user: "The state implementation in the App SDK is provided by the Ext.state.Stateful mixin. Values are stored in Preference objects in CA Agile Central scoped to the app and current user."

My question is, is there a way to make those Preference objects scoped to the whole subscription, and not only to the current user? so that if I have a custom app, all the users in our rally subscription can log in an view the changes that themselves and others have made. Thank you.

***EDIT***

This is the code, I am just testing state by adding numbers to an array after adding a dialog. I used initComponent as per Kyle's answer, but statefulness stops working when including it (it's commented out right now):

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
stateful: true,
componentCls: 'app',

// initComponent: function() {
//     console.log('called initComponent');
//     this.stateId = Ext.create('Rally.state.ScopedStateUtil').getScopedStateId('appState', {
//         appID: this.getContext().getAppId(),
//         workspace: this.getContext().getWorkspaceRef()
//     });

//     this.callParent(arguments);
// },

getState: function() {
    console.log('getting state');

    if(this.dialogs.length > 0) {
        var newState = {
            currentDialogs: [].concat(this.dialogs)
        };
        console.log('this is the new state:', newState);
        return newState;
    }
    console.log('returning null from getState');
    return null;
},

applyState: function(state) {
    console.log('applying state');
    console.log('current state:', state);

    if(state.currentDialogs) {
        this.dialogs = state.currentDialogs;    
        console.log('this.dialogs after applying state:', this.dialogs);
    }
    else {
        this.dialogs = [];
        console.log('this.dialogs did not exit before. just created it.');
    }
},

doLayout: function() {
    var me = this;
    var textField = Ext.create('Rally.ui.TextField', {
        fieldLabel: 'Add task:',
        listeners: {
            scope: me, 
            specialkey: me._checkEnter
        }
    });

    me.add(textField);
},

launch: function() {
    if(!this.dialogs) {
        this.dialogs = [];
        console.log('just created dialogs');
    }
    this.doLayout();
    this.taskCounter = 0;
    this.yPosition = 50;
},

_checkEnter: function(field, event) {
    if (event.getKey() === event.ENTER) {
        this._onEnter(field);
    }
},

_onEnter: function(field) {
    this.taskCounter = this.taskCounter + 1;
    var dialog = Ext.create(Rally.ui.dialog.Dialog, {
        context: this.getContext(),
        autoShow: true,
        autoCenter: false,
        draggable: false,
        closable: true,
        modal: false,
        width: 300,
        x: 100,
        y: this.yPosition,
        title: 'Task ' + this.taskCounter,
        items: {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: field.getRawValue(),
            padding: 10
        }
    });

    this.yPosition = this.yPosition + 100;
    this.dialogs.push((99990 + this.taskCounter).toString());
    this.saveState();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I investigated some more and it seems like statefulness is hard-wired to work per user and will be pretty hard to work around.  Instead you should be able to do it using settings though:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    doLayout: function() {
        var me = this;
        var textField = Ext.create('Rally.ui.TextField', {
            fieldLabel: 'Add task:',
            listeners: {
                scope: me,
                specialkey: me._checkEnter
            }
        });

        me.add(textField);
    },

    launch: function() {
        var dialogs = this.getSetting('dialogs');
        this.dialogs = (dialogs || '').split(',');
        console.log(this.dialogs);

        //TODO: if dialogs exist draw them

        this.doLayout();
        this.taskCounter = 0;
        this.yPosition = 50;
    },

    _checkEnter: function(field, event) {
        if (event.getKey() === event.ENTER) {
            this._onEnter(field);
        }
    },

    _onEnter: function(field) {
        this.taskCounter = this.taskCounter + 1;
        var dialog = Ext.create(Rally.ui.dialog.Dialog, {
            context: this.getContext(),
            autoShow: true,
            autoCenter: false,
            draggable: false,
            closable: true,
            modal: false,
            width: 300,
            x: 100,
            y: this.yPosition,
            title: 'Task ' + this.taskCounter,
            items: {
                xtype: 'component',
                html: field.getRawValue(),
                padding: 10
            }
        });

        this.yPosition = this.yPosition + 100;
        this.dialogs.push((99990 + this.taskCounter).toString());
        this._persistDialogs();
    },

    _persistDialogs: function() {
        this.updateSettingsValues({
            settings: {
                dialogs: this.dialogs
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where exactly would I call initComponent for it to work properly? because right now the app is getting an automatic stateId when it first loads, and when I change it using the function you provided, it doesn't save anything new, and on reload, the id gets changed back to the one that was automatically assigned (I am logging the stateId to the console when the app loads). Thanks.

Comment: that initComponent should just be part of your App.js.  you can put it right above your launch function.

Comment: Ok, I just tested this. My app was saving state correctly, it called getState and applyState as it should. But, when I add the initComponent, it stops calling applyState.

Comment: Here's my code for your reference, if you comment in the initComponent function, the statefulness stops working, since applyState stops being called on app launch:

Comment: Hey kyle, I know you get thousands of questions posted here and can't really answer all of them, but if you could take a look at the code I posted it I would greatly appreciate, since I still haven't found a way to make it work. Thanks for all your help. Cheers.